# Single code base for mobile and desktop app

Tags: mobile, desktop

We have a requirement to work on an application which should run on mobile devices (iPhone/Android and Windows Phone) and Desktop browsers.

Can anyone please suggest me the technology stack to be used?

Thanks.
Suhas

Comment: What you want is a mobile friendly web design, except if you want "real" apps on the phone. If so, take a look at phonegap.

Comment: question not clear..or you want us to work for you from scratch..make it clear ..please..

Comment: It will be an application (may be HTML5/JS) which is supposed to work on multiple mobile devices and desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-platform HTML-app solutions seem like a good fit for this. They are cross platform app development platforms that are composed of HTML, CSS and JavaScript. They would allow you to compile for many platforms from a single codebase. Here's a few of the popular ones:

1. [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)
2. [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)
3. [AppJS](http://appjs.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But will PhoneGap allow me to develop for desktop? Any thoughts on using Sencha Touch 2?

Comment: None of those linked will allow you to develop for desktop browsers, they're just cross-mobile solutions. And you wouldn't really need a framework for desktop browsers - they already run HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: So does that mean that we will have to write HTML pages to run on both mobile and desktop browsers - or you see them as two different code bases?

Answer (score 0):

2022 We have two popular frameworks that build app for multiple platforms, for more information you could visit their home pages:

1. [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) (mobile, web, desktop and embedded apps)
2. [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) (mobile), [React Native Desktop](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31291471)